# How to Create a PEM File from Windows

Tags: linux, openssl, putty, pem, domain-name

I have four linux servers, and want the server to connect to XY Server, where i have the PEM keys for XY server.Now i need to create a PEM files for the 4 linux servers.

I am connecting to the 4 linux server through putty from windows.

Can any help me, how to generate the PEM files in windows for the 4 linux servers.

Thanks

Comment: You can install OpenSSL for Win32 (maybe as part of a larger Unix support package like Interix/Microsoft SFU/SUA, or Cygwin) and then use the [openssl(1)](https://www.mirbsd.org/man1/openssltool) command like you do on GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Your PEM files whether generated on Windows or Linux will work on the platforms or systems which understands PEM.

You can generate same file on Linux using OpenSSL commands and then use them on Windows.